# Copying data from one page to another depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, copying

This code copies the entire row to another when the word 'ordered' is in a certain column.

However, I need to adapt this code to not copy the entire row for another function but requires only copying columns A:J over into the next sheet but I'm having difficulty achieving this.

```
Sub MovingOrderedItems()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim Z As Long
    X = Worksheets("Engineer-Items to be ordered").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Y = Worksheets("Admin").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Y = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Admin").UsedRange) = 0 Then Y = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Engineer-Items to be ordered").Range("N3:N" & X)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Z = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(Z).Value) = "ordered" Then
            xRg(Z).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Admin").Range("A" & Y + 1)
            xRg(Z).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(Z).Value) = "ordered" Then
                 Z = Z - 1
            End If
            Y = Y + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Much better to use `Range.AutoFilter` or `Range.AdvancedFilter`, instead of looping.

Comment: Also note that you need to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages until `End Sub` but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. So if there occur errors and you don't get notified you will not be able to fix these errors and if you don't fix them of course your code cannot work properly. Using this line as you did is dangerous. Remove it and fix your errors. Also see [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Comment: I think the problem might in the line `xRg(Z).EntireRow.Copy`. You are coping the entire row. Therefore you'll paste the entire row. It doesn't matter if the destination is limited to the A-J columns. Try by coping just the range you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but you can replace

```
xRg(Z).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Admin").Range("A" & Y + 1)
```

With

```
Range(xRg(Z).EntireRow.Cells(1, 1), xRg(Z).EntireRow.Cells(1, 10)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Admin").Range("A" & Y + 1)
```